# Deploying JPA 2 (OpenJPA) on Jboss 7.1.0-Final-Snapshot

Tags: openjpa, jboss7.x

I have deployed axis2 on Jboss 7.1.0 Final Snapshot. We have a service (.aar) which uses OPenJPA 2.1.
All the OpenJPA jars are packaged within the service archive.

When I start the server I see this error message

Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named example

I have defined the provider in the persistence.xml as org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl

Structure of my Service is as follows,
SampleOpenJPAService.aar
     |-lib
        |-myJPAClasses.jar

Can anyone help me in understanding What is going wrong here.

regards,

sathwik

Comment: I suppose support for OpenJPA was added only in 7.1.0

Comment: I went ahead and deployed a simple web application which uses OpenJPA.

Comment: My module.xml of openjpa is as follows

`<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.openjpa">
<resources>
<resource-root path="openjpa-2.1.0.jar"/>
<resource-root path="serp-1.13.1.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
<module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
<module name="javax.validation.api"/>
<module name="org.apache.commons.lang"/>
<module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
<module name="org.apache.log4j"/>        
</dependencies>
</module>`

Comment: Now added the dependency for openjpa in my jboss-deployment-structure.xml within my application.
`<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
      <dependencies>
        <module name="org.apache.openjpa" />
      </dependencies>
  </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>`

Comment: But deployment failed with the exception:
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider 'org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl' not found

Comment: Following this forum post https://community.jboss.org/message/629691#629691
I added the property in my persistence.xml
`<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.apache.openjpa" />`
Removed the openjpa module dependency from Jboss-deployment-structure.xml
This deployed the web application successfully.